# What's wrong with my requests.Session for python crawler?

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm coding a crawler for www.researchgate.net, but it seems that I'll be stuck in the login page forever.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

params = {'login': 'my_email', 'password': 'my_password'}
session.post("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html", data = params)
s = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/search.Search.html?type=researcher&query=zhang")
print BeautifulSoup(s.text).title
```

Can anybody find anything wrong with my code? Why does s redirect to login page every time?

Comment: you did not provide all creditential for the authentification. Check in your browser what you send to the network to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hidden fields in the login form that probably need to be supplied (I can't test - I don't have a login there).

One is `request_token` which is set to a long base64 encoded string. Others are `invalidPasswordCount` and `loginCookie` which might also be required.

Further to that there is a session cookie that you might need to send with the login credentials.

To make this work will require an initial `GET` to get the `request_token`, which you need to extract somehow - e.g. with BeautifulSoup. If you use your `requests` session then the cookie will be presented in the following `POST`, so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

# initial GET to retrieve token and set cookies
r = session.get('https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html')
soup = r.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
request_token = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':'request_token'})['value']

params = {'login': 'my_email', 'password': 'my_password', 'request_token': request_token, 'invalidPasswordCount': 0, 'loginCookie': 'yes'}
session.post("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html", data=params)
s = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/search.Search.html?type=researcher&query=zhang")
print BeautifulSoup(s.text).title
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I successfully log in, finally!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mhawke, I modified my original code as he suggested and I finally logged in successfully.

Here's my new code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
loginpage = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html")
request_token = BeautifulSoup(loginpage.text).form.find("input",{"name":"request_token"}).attrs["value"]
print request_token
params = {"request_token":request_token,
          "invalidPasswordCount":"0",
          'login': 'my_email', 
          'password': 'my_password',
          "setLoginCookie":"yes"
          }
session.post("https://www.researchgate.net/application.Login.html", data = params)
#print s.cookies.get_dict()
s = session.get("https://www.researchgate.net/search.Search.html?type=researcher&query=zhang")
print BeautifulSoup(s.text).title
```